# SpringBoot 1.4 shutdown itself periodly

Tags: spring-boot

I got a problem that my springboot web app shutdown periodly. 
I can find some exception in logs.

```
2017-08-16 20:43:01.376  INFO 24942 --- [       Thread-3] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6659c656: startup date [Wed Aug 09 09:09:44 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-08-16 20:43:01.381  INFO 24942 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

Comment: Can you check any other services running on that port ? You should try to close/kill those processes if it is running on port like 8080 etc other than your webapp application.

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency in pom.xml

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```